# In a world where mankind is ruled by a giant intelligent beaver, what food is no longer consumed (by humans)?

Tags: science-based, biology, science-fiction, politics, food

Pretend I'm writing a novel about a how a beaver takes over the world: What food/s may/might/(grammar?) no longer be consumed by humans or at least consumed less?

---

**Edit 1**: I was wondering if anyone would google this. This is from [The Big Bang Theory S04E03](https://bigbangtrans.wordpress.com/series-4-episode-03-the-zazzy-substitution/). The 2 askers, Amy and Sheldon, claim is that there exists a unique answer 'cheese Danish'. However the answerer Leonard guessed cinnamon and gave a really good YET SIMPLE/ELEGANT/SUCCINCT explanation.

I wanted to see others' opinions and so I made this question into like writing a novel.

The [ff](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/207002/in-a-world-where-mankind-is-ruled-by-a-giant-intelligent-beaver-what-food-is-no#comment641025_207002) is one of the comments I got (pretty much the same answer as Leonard):

> Wood. All wood goes to holy beavers. Potencial to deduce things in the A for the q is quite low, if there is something to deduce scientifically at all. Opinion based vtc, hm? Extencion defining properties of those beavers may or may not be an improvement for the q. – [MolbOrg](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/20315/molborg)

Genius question/observation comments:

1. > I don't get why some foods woukld no longer be consumed in a world ruled by an intelligent beaver in the first place. The question should be edited to explain why promoting an intelligent beaver to the position of world emperor would lead to some foods becoming unavailable. – AlexP 5 hours ago
2. > It's not clear to me : What is the relationship between the beaver-se and the human-iverse? Is it equal on equal, humans fighting for their survival against bearzillas, or are humans down to the level of animals (think "Planet of the apes")...? What do you mean by "giant"? There can be wide changes just because of that :)  Tortliena

---

**Edit 2**: Why off-topic? i mean really suppose i'm writing a novel about such a beaver. then the plot is about how humans rebel. and then it's a subplot that humans in general miss a certain kind of food because the beaver took it away. **MolbOrg's comment got 5 upvotes. I say we let it be the accepted answer.**

Comment: Wood. All wood goes to holy beavers. Potencial to deduce things in the A for the q is quite low, if there is something to deduce scientifically at all. Opinion based vtc, hm? Extencion defining properties of those beavers may or may not be an improvement for the q.

Comment: @MolbOrg do you mean wood-related food products will not be eaten and so we should think about what food products are wood-related eg cinnamon? thanks!

Comment: I don't get why some foods woukld no longer be consumed in a world ruled by an intelligent beaver in the first place. The question should be edited to explain *why* promoting an intelligent beaver to the position of world emperor would lead to some foods becoming unavailable.

Comment: @AlexP good point in not seeing. edited question.

Comment: It's not clear to me : What is the relationship between the beaver-se and the human-iverse? Is it equal on equal, humans fighting for their survival against bearzillas, or are humans down to the level of animals (think "[Planet of the apes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_the_Apes_(1968_film))")...? What do you mean by "giant"? There can be wide changes just because of that :).

Comment: Beaver is no longer on the menu obviously. but why would having a beaver overlord change the eating habits of his subjects? we don't generally try to change the eating habits of animals even in our zoos.

Comment: +1 to @Tortliena's question. Also, is it just one mastermind beaver, or all beavers are at least somewhat intelligent and have something that resembles a civilization?

Comment: @ITAlex edited to just humans. my bad. please see the rest of the edit too lol

Comment: @Alexander good question. hell if i know. but i think just 1 beaver...[since no indication of other beavers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2682173/can-deer-be-at-the-zoo-if-there-are-deer-at-the-zoo-and-some-deer-have-antlers). please see edit.

Comment: @Tortliena genius questions. please see edit

Comment: @MolbOrg see my edit. good job XD also do you think this could be made on-topic ? i mean really suppose i'm writing a novel about such a beaver. then the plot is about how humans rebel. and then it's a subplot that humans in general miss a certain kind of food.

Comment: The only reasonable answer is "whatever the beaver wants" - given the total lack of detail in the question, its motivations and goals are utterly inscrutable. It might be a benevolent ruler and let us carry on as before, or a cruel one and force us to eat nothing but worms. You're basically asking where a 500lb gorilla sits - wherever it wants. What is the beaver trying to *achieve* by limiting certain foods?

Comment: I share your sorrow, also have no idea why my [q](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/198172/20315) is offtopic, lol, generally it is(ontopic offtopic) is meta questions and you can find there many examples and many different reasons, so I suggest to read some. After edit I understand the premise of q better, why u ask it. The problem with the q poorly defined starting conditions, we know nothing about situation, and because of that any answer is about how good a fantasy one has. I see u on scifi.se, we try to use more science and less fantasy, to improve someones work

Comment: I'd say that you need a refresher course in how we do things. Comments aren't answers, editing a question in such a way as you have is frankly bizarre and not helpful. Please refer to the [help] for guidance, particularly the post referred to on meta regarding [the ideal question - checklist.](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3624/how-to-write-the-perfect-question)

Comment: My comment was upvoted not because people think that wood is a good answer, but because instead of wood there can be anything and that anything can have chain of reasoning. As in  Nuclear Hoagie comment, whatever beavers want. They can forbid something on the whimp just to show authority or target some groups of people etc. There is no end to all the possibilities, it just about how good someones fantasy is and how skillful they are at creating believable reasoning. Try quora they like short questions, and maybe it gains some attencion, as it does not require any expert knowledge to make an A.

Comment: If u like to write in such setting then basically nothing restrains you, you can unleash yourself, and choose -maybe you would like to be more humorous and rebel of humans happened because of lack of ice-cream as the straw which broke the camel back.  Or be more med dark inclined - everyone now eat polished rice as staple food and not much else and have Scurvy. Again, it depends on your choices. An attempt could be - what food defficiency for time[defined by u] can result serious enough consequences[define some range] so it worth to wage a rebellion - not much better than u q atm  but maybe

Comment: And btw u q is not offtopic, but opinion based - that is a significant difference here on wb. We have nothing against giant beaver(s) dominating over humanity, lol

Comment: Your question only has a single giant intelligent beaver, which rules the human race.